# Getting string for database and use it as img src

Tags: php, html

I have problem looping out pictures from a database.
I have no problem getting the information(string) that I need from the database. The problems accure when I try to use the string as a img src-tag.

My code:

```
<?php

foreach ($console as $con):

echo '<li>', $con['brand'], ', ',$con['pic'], '</li>';

echo'<div class="item2">
        <a href="xboxconsol.html">
            <img src=',$con['pic'],'/>
        </a>
    </div>';
endforeach;
?>
```

Note, the li-elements put out the correct information but when I use it in the img-tag it adds a "/" at the end on the string.

Example of list output:
Playstation, ../playstation.jpg

The picutre however output the URL to the pic as:
../playstation.jpg/

Where do the last "/" come from and how do I get rid of it?

Comment: The last "/" is closing the img tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to quote the attribute value.

```
echo'<div class="item2">
    <a href="xboxconsol.html">
        <img src="',$con['pic'],'"/>
    </a>
</div>';
```

Currently the browser is guessing what the attribute should contain.

Which comes out as:

```
<img src="value/">
```

but you want:

```
<img src="value"/>
```

Comment: `<img src="',$con['pic'],'"/>` should be `<img src="'.$con['pic'].'"/>`

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile it is an `echo`, that is supported. (I do prefer the concatenation syntax, but that's a personal preference, OP can use either)

Answer (score 1):

You need to quote your concatenations, be very careful how you output HTML from PHP.

I'd rather concatenate the variables like this instead:

```
foreach ($console as $con)
{
    echo "<li>{$con['brand']} {$con['pic']}</li>";
    echo "<div class='item2'>
            <a href='xboxconsol.html'>
                <img src=\"{$con['pic']}\" />
            </a>
        </div>";
}
```

It's way cleaner and more readable.

Comment: Sorry about it. Fixed it.